# SelectMultiple form field with CharFiled in django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Match model:

```
class Match(models.Model):
  base_f = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  base_v = models.IntegerField()
  dest_f = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  dest_v = models.IntegerField()
```

I have created a model form from `Match` model:

```
class MatchForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Match
       widgets = {
           'base_f':forms.Select(choices=base_fs, attrs={'class':'base_f'}),
           'base_v':forms.Select(attrs={'class':'dest_v'}),
           'dest_f':forms.Select(choices=dest_fs, attrs={'class':'dest_f'}),
           'dest_v':forms.Select(attrs={'class':'dest_v'}),
        }
```

form.save() works fine for this model form. But I want to use `SelectMultiple`. But form.save() doesnt add any data in database with below form:

```
class MatchForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Match
       widgets = {
           'base_f':forms.Select(choices=base_fs, attrs={'class':'base_f'}),
           'base_v':forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'dest_v'}),
           'dest_f':forms.Select(choices=dest_fs, attrs={'class':'dest_f'}),
           'dest_v':forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'dest_v'}),
        }
```

Ho can I use SelectMultiple model with CharFiled in django?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't store more than one value in a CharField. You can provide choices for a CharField and store one choice, but not multiple choices.

If you need to store more than one value, you'll need to make the model your storing more than one instance of a ManyToMany field.

Comment: I want bulk insert. Is it possible for do this with this model and model form? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's what formsets are for: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/formsets/